# footer different section heights

Tags: css, position, footer

So i'm doing this project and i'm stuck with the footer. I am having this problem where the second section of the footer gets bigger and goes out of the footer. Another thing is when I do float:left; on the third section of the footer, footer's background goes away. So my question is, how do I contain everything within the footer. Here's the codepen - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gxjbyg .

If I do this:

```
footer {
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
clear: both;
position:absolute;
width:100%;
bottom:0;
}
```

It kinda gets fixed, but i'm wondering if there is another way, while not using the absolute positioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what you expect?

```
footer {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
 clear: both;
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yup..Maybe you or some one could explain why the footer doesn't go full height without this fix? Also I tried to make it display:block; and it worked as well.

Comment: @BenasLengvinas the footer doesn't go full height because you have floating content inside it. If you don't set `display: table` to wrapper all content up or add a clearfix to the footer, it doesn't consider floating elements to set its height.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the clearfix css trick that is used for fixing the height of a parent container which has floating children elements. What you want to do in your code that you posted on codepen is make the #left, #center and #right elements float left and then apply the clearfix class to the footer element which is the parent of this three floating elements. Here is a sample code of how that would look like in code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .clearfix:after{
            content: "";
            display: table;
            clear: both;
        }
        #left, #center, #right{
            float:left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<footer class="clearfix">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="center"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</footer>
```

Comment: I see that @nersoh solution gets the same result as yours, which solution would you say is better?

Comment: It is basically the same thing but I'd recommend my solution because it follows the clean coding practices of reusability and single responsibility. That means that our .clearfix class is only responsible for "fixing" the layout when an element has a floating children and it can be easily reused to any other element which needs it in addition to other css classes applied to the same element for different styling purposes.

Comment: Here is a link in case you are interested how the .clearfix solution has been evolving in the past: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that your problem is that you have `#top` and `#bottom` both set to a height of 50% with additional padding of 20px on each. If you look at your overlap, it's 40px.

To fix this, set your height to something like 45% and padding to 5%. That will probably achieve the behavior that you're looking for.